# How to disable redirection of http to https (Nginx, CertBot)

Tags: http, nginx, web, https, server

Im trying to not redirect http to https....

I tried to research but found *nothing*...

BTW I DID BOTH THIS COMMANDS TO MAKE NEW FILE INSTEAD OF USING DEFAULT FILE ON SITES ENABLED:

```
sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/imallbd
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/imallbd
```

then:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/imallbd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/imallbd
```

**This is my sites-enabled file**

```
server {

    server_name imallbd.com;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # For API
    location /api {
        alias /var/www/imallbd/api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
            location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         }
    }

    location @api {
      rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # For FrontEnd -> GraphQL
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /admin{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/admin;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/imallbd.com/fullchain.pem; # managed >
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/imallbd.com/privkey.pem; # manage>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = imallbd.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name imallbd.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

pls help!!! btw when i go to my website it gives me 502 bad gateway... ik thats not the question im asking but if you can give me some help tips or the answer i would be so grateful :)

when i run:

```
sudo nginx -t

   nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

If you want more details or information i can give, just tell me on the comments!

**THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all why do you want to remove the https redirect ?

Either way you can remove this part:

```
if ($host = imallbd.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

This will remove the http -> https redirect.

Also, if you make any changes in nginx you need to restart te service.
assuming you are using a linux based os run:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

The problem of your 502 error of nginx has to do with php.

The php process is not running, has crashed or nginx cannot communicate with it.

What kind of php instalation do you have ? php-fpm ? If that's the case run

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

If not. Let me know in the comments (not enough rep to say this in the comments)

Comment: i want to not redirect to https because its giving me error since my link is http and also, yes i am using php-fpm. thank you for posting the answer im gonna try it right now

Comment: Hi xAtifx I understand that. That is why you need to remove:
```
if ($host = imallbd.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

The 301 is a status code of moved permanantly. This redirects everything from port 80 (aka http) to https://$host

Zo if you remove that it wont redirect to https anymore

Comment: i fixed it myself already but some of your answer helped me so enjoy the upvote and check :)